# Agrgumental Error in finding LCM using Python what am i doing wrong

Tags: python, syntax-error, calculation, lcm

Hi I am experiencing a issue with writing a code to find lcm of 2 numbers the code is as follows

```
   def compute_lcm(x, y):

   if x > y:
       greater = x
   else:
       greater = y

   while(True):
       if((greater % x == 0) and (greater % y == 0)):
           lcm = greater
           break
       greater += 1

   return lcm

num1 = input("Number1 ")
num2 = input("Number2 ")

print("The L.C.M. is", compute_lcm(num1, num2))
```

result:-

```
PS C:\Users\Amrit Shahi\Desktop> & "C:/Users/Amrit 
Shahi/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe" "c:/Users/Amrit 
Shahi/Desktop/Test.py"
Number1 35
Number2 23
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Amrit Shahi\Desktop\Test.py", line 19, in <module>
    print("The L.C.M. is", compute_lcm(num1, num2))
  File "c:\Users\Amrit Shahi\Desktop\Test.py", line 9, in compute_lcm
    if((greater % x == 0) and (greater % y == 0)):
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

To add I am using vs code

Comment: In Python 3 `input()` always returns a string.  Change them to `num = int(input("Number"))`.  That will convert them to integers.

Comment: Also, it's hard to imagine a less efficient lcm algorithm.  It won't work for large numbers (it will take too long to finish).  Just find the gcd (which is available as `math.gcd`), then divide the product by the gcd to obtain the lcm.  If you instead want to write your own gcd algorithm, use [Euclid's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm).